# open FIND dialogue in Yakuake with shortcut

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, kde, konsole

Is there some way to set a keyboard shortcut to open the Search/Find dialogue in Yakuake rather than <kbd>Right click</kbd> then <kbd>Find</kbd>? I can't find one for the life of me and opening the dialogue with the mouse each time is driving me crazy.

I am running tumbleweed, if that matters.

Comment: Not a solution, but a workaround for just a tab in the current session: right clicking on the Search/Find element on the right click menu allows you to set a shortcut for the current tab. If you, like me, have long-running tabs, that's a way to ease the pain.

Answer (score 1):

Yakuake utilizes KPart, which is the embedded version of Konsole.

KPart is initialized slightly different from the full version of Konsole and thus doesn't have default shortcuts for {Find,FindNext,FindPrev} actions.

I couldn't find any easy way to expose KPart actions to Yakuake for shortcuts customization. The only way I've found so far is to reconfigure the default shortcuts, which is hardcoded to be empty.

You can find my commit here: https://github.com/phuongfi91/konsole/commit/d1ae510bdc4b08387f1fb8a628db85d5e7e3c294

Or the diff here:
https://github.com/phuongfi91/konsole/commit/d1ae510bdc4b08387f1fb8a628db85d5e7e3c294.diff

Then get a suitable release for your system, apply the patch, build and install it:
https://github.com/KDE/konsole/releases

Please let me know if anyone manages to find a better solution, because I'm curious as well.